# I'm unable to deploy grails application on tomcat 8.0.36 / 8.0.24 on linux with java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 0 in class file

Tags: linux, tomcat, grails, deployment, tomcat8

I'm unable to deploy grails 2.5.0 application on tomcat 8 running on linux machine. The same application is running fine on windows. While deploying the server start up would fail because of some or the other class .

```
2016-11-29 05:09:06,234 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 0 in class file MarkdownGrailsPlugin$_closure1$_closure2
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2541)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:858)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1301)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    at MarkdownGrailsPlugin$_closure1.doCall(MarkdownGrailsPlugin.groovy:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

The checksum of the class file that is getting error does not match with what i have on windows machine after the deployment.But when I add the class file in `WEB-INF/classes` server starts but it fails in loading some other resource or in GSP compilation . The same application , same war is working fine on windows and on vm box of linux .

JDK / JRE and even patch level is same on the windows , linux machine . Is there any os parameters that has to be increased .

Details of JDK / JRE on linux machine where the issue is faced .

```
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.966 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.968 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 9 2016 13:55:50 UTC
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.968 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.36.0
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.968 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.968 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            2.6.18-416.el5
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.969 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.969 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.969 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b15
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.969 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.969 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /home/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.36
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.969 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /home/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.36
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.970 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/conf/logging.properties
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.970 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.970 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms2g
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.970 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx4g
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.971 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.971 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttp.proxyHost=www-proxy.sct.com
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.971 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.971 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.971 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms2g
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.971 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx4g
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.971 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.972 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttp.proxyHost=www-proxy.sct.com
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.972 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.972 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.972 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8999
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.972 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.972 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.972 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=149.24.37.131
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.973 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/endorsed
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.973 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.36
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.973 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.36
29-Nov-2016 05:07:40.973 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/temp
```

The same application is working fine on windows machine

```
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.007 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.009 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 9 2016 13:55:50 UTC
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.010 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.36.0
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.011 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 8.1
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.012 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.3
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.012 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.013 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.013 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b15
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.014 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.014 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\sandbox\apache-tomcat-8.0.36
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.015 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\sandbox\apache-tomcat-8.0.36
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.015 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.016 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:PermSize=512m
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.016 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms2048m
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.017 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx4096m
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.017 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DPROXY_SERVER_NAME=http://m039220:8081/nexus/content/groups/public
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.017 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.018 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\sandbox\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\conf\logging.properties
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.019 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.027 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms512m
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.029 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1524m
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.035 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:PermSize=256m
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.036 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.042 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.049 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.050 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.086 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\sandbox\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\endorsed
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.087 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\sandbox\apache-tomcat-8.0.36
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.093 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\sandbox\apache-tomcat-8.0.36
30-Nov-2016 22:17:29.095 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sandbox\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\temp
```

Is there any native library that i need to check or some OS parameter that i needs to be tweaked ?

Answer (score 1):

Issue was with the open files on the server . In VM the value was set to 4096 where as on server where we were facing the issue was set to 1024.

After increasing the open files to 4096 , server started working . The application seems to be heavy with 15000 odd files in the war .

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the class has been compiled for Java 8, and your JVM is Java 7. This can be either an error in Grails (Markdown plug-in) distribution, or you've mixed the versions.

Comment: Compiled on the same version of JDK .